# When run this code it always showing the result Promise { <pending> }

Tags: mongodb

get_cart_products:(user_id)=>{
return new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=>{
let product=await db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION).find({user_id:objectId(user_id)}).toArray()
resolve(product)
})
},

It always showing the result Promise {  }

Answer (score 0):

It seem fairly obvious to get that when you create a promise. To recieve the actual value you will need to use async/await.

```
async function handler(){
    const data = await get_cart_products() //Promise resolved
}
```

Now you can use the data inside the handler to execute the code you need.